# Push View from Presented View Controller in Swift 3,4,5

Tags: ios, swift

How can I push the view controller from the presented `ViewController`?

I have `MainViewController`, In which I have one button on click of a button, I am presenting a view called `LoginViewController`.

On this page (`LoginViewController`), I also have a button, on click of that, I try to push my view controller (called `HomeViewController`). But, it doesn't push.

How can I solve that?

Comment: How are you trying to push it? Navigation Controller?

Comment: Please try to give more details and be specific. Also add your code here to show your work so far.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to push view controller onto the navigation stack, you need to have a `navigation controller` at the root of the presented view controller. So instead of presenting the `LoginViewController`, embed it in a `navigation controller` and present that `navigation controller`.

```
let loginVC = ...
let loginNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginVC)
loginNavController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
present(loginNavController, animated: true)
```